# MongoDB - index an internal list of objects

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Assume the following data structure in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : "Bob Blocker",
    "ratings" : {
        "771206753" : 1
    },
    "prevalence" : 1
}
```

How could one index the keys of the internal structure of `ratings` using `ensureIndex()`?  I would want to build an index that associated the document `_id` with any and all of the keys (in this example, "771206753") in the ratings object.

Would keying the index with `ratings` suffice?  Wouldn't that also record the value portion of the ratings object?  Should I shift my schema if lookup is intended by that particular key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't index dynamic keys and indexing `ratings` would index the whole object as a blob so you don't want to do that either.

It may work better to rework your schema to:

```
{
    "_id" : "Bob Blocker",
    "ratings" : [
        {id: "771206753", value: 1}
    ],
    "prevalence" : 1
}
```

and then index `'ratings.id'`.